# Delphi - TPlannerMonthView set Item Color

Tags: delphi, background-color, tms

im trying build a darkmode for my programm and now i have again a problem with the PlannerMonthView from TMS. You can change close to any color of the Month Planner but not the Item Color. Does anyone know how to change it to a diffrent Color like grey or something like that?

Comment: What do TMS support say about this?

Comment: Taking a brief look at the docs, various items seem to have color properties, so please be more specific what class you ask about.

Comment: Yes there are some color properties but not for the Background color of an item. I have create a Planner with Items like Notes. So and now im trying to change the color of the Planner to a little darker one like dark mode. Thats works perfectly except the Item background color. I cant change it from white to a other color like grey or something like that.

Comment: I repeat, what class do you ask about when you say "item". Or actually, maybe you should just turn to TMS.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what class it is i think it is the item class from TPlannerMonthView but i mean with "Item" an item what you can create with PlannerMontView1.createitem so that shows an item in the Planner like in a calendar. So and my problem is that the background color of the Item is white and i want to change it. Sorry im new in delphi and i dont know that mutch. I can show it to you with a screenshot.  https://prnt.sc/1tbukkg

Comment: Ok, I don't have the planner, so I can not test myself. But looking at the [doc](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/Download/Manuals/TMS%20TPLANNER.pdf) on page 8, most of the items have some color fill and looking further at page 11 onwards, `Background` is mentioned to set bg color, as well as `Color` and `ItemColor`. I hope you can take it from there, otherwise really ask TMS, they are known for providing good user support.

Comment: Yeah i allready test the ItemColor from the normal Planner but it is not working with the PlannerMonthView component just with the normal Planner. But thanks for your help

Comment: In the referred doc on page 30 is a picture of an item editor that has settings for `background`, `selected background`.

Comment: yeah i see but thats the TMS Planner component not the PlannerMonthView. With the normal Planner you can select a item background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set then TPlannerMonthViewItems[n].color to desired color

```
  with PlannerMonthView.CreateItem do
  begin
    id            := 1;
    Color         := clGray;
    CaptionBkg    := Color;
    shadow        := true;
    Text.Text     := 'Test1';
    ItemStartTime := StrToDate('21/09/2021');
    ItemEndTime   := StrToDate('21/09/2021');
  end;
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out. From where do i get these information? but a little question i have. how i can change the item from/to color? now its like a color transition https://prnt.sc/1tc6izr

Answer (score 0):

From TMS's TPlanner manual
**
**Additional properties that control the appearance of a TPlannerItem in the grid are:**

**Alignment**: sets the alignment of text in the TPlannerItem

**Attachement**: string that can point to an attachement. If Attachement is a non-empty string, this is
indicated by a clip in the TPlannerItem caption

**Background**: when true, the item is displayed without selectable border and cannot be moved or
sized as such.

**BorderColor**: sets the color of the border of the TPlannerItem

**BrushStyle**: sets the background brush style of the TPlannerItem

**CaptionAlign**: sets the alignment of the TPlannerItem caption text

**CaptionBkg**: sets the background color of the TPlannerItem caption. This property has no effect
when UniformBkg is true, as the TPlannerItem will always have a full uniform color

**CaptionBkgTo**: when different from clNone and UniformBkg is false, the caption is drawn with a
gradient from CaptionBkg color to CaptionBkgTo color

**CaptionBkgDirection**: sets the caption background gradient direction

**CaptionFont**: sets the font for the TPlannerItem caption

**CaptionText**: sets the text for the caption. This text is only displayed when CaptinTupe is either
ctText or ctTimeText

**CaptionType**: can be

- ctNone : no caption is displayed
- ctText : CaptionText is displayed
- ctTime : time of item is displayed
- ctTimeText : time and CaptionText are displayed at the same time

**Color**: sets the background color of the TPlannerItem

**ColorTo**: sets the gradient end color for the background of the TPlannerItem. When set to clNone,
the background is drawn in a solid color.

**ColorDirection**: sets the item background gradient direction

**Completion**: sets the completion of the item. This is a value between 0 and 100.

**CompletionDisplay**: sets where to display the completion. The value can be : cdNone, cdVertical,
cdHorizontal.

**Cursor**: sets the cursor that is used when mouse is over the item. If Cursor is -1, default cursors are
used.

**DrawTool**: this assigns a component that encapsulates custom drawing for the TPlannerItem. If a
drawtool component is assigned, this component will draw the item in the planner.

**Editor**: sets the instance of the editor component that will be used to edit the item.

**EditMask**: sets the edit mask that will be used when the inplace editor type is peEditMask.

**Font**: sets the font of the TPlannerItem

**HintIndicator**: When true, a small triangle is displayed in the top right corner of the item to
indicate that a hint is available for the item. When HintIndicator is shown only when the Hint
property is also a non-empty string.

**HintIndicatorColor**: Sets the color of the small triangle indicating a hint exists of the item.

**ImageID**: sets the index of the image from an attached imagelist to display in the TPlannerItem

**ImagePosition**: sets the position of the associated image(s) to display.

**InHeader**: when true, the item is displayed inside the TPlanner header

**SelectColor**: sets the color of the item when it is selected

**SelectColorTo**: sets the gradient end color of the item when it is selected

**SelectFontColor**: sets the font color of the item when it is selected

**Shadow**: when true, the TPlannerItem is displayed with a shadow. The shadow color is set with the
property TPlanner.ShadowColor

**Shape**: sets the shape of the TPlannerItem to rectangle, hexagon, rounded rectangle or skinned.
When skinned, the Planner Skin is used to draw the item.

**ShowDeleteButton**: when true, a delete button is displayed in the upper right corner of the planner
item.

**ShowLinks**: when true, a chain icon is displayed to show the item is linked to another TPlannerItem

**ShowSelection**: when true, selected items are displayed with SelectColor and SelectFontColor

**Text**: the stringlist through which the TPlannerItem text is set

**TrackBrushStyle**: sets the brush to be used for painting the trackbar of the item

**TrackColor**: sets the color of the trackbar. The trackbar is the small colored bar with which the
item can be dragged and moved inside the planner grid.

**TrackSelectColor**: sets the color of the trackbar when the item is selected

**TrackLinkColor**: sets the color of the trackbar when a linked item is selected.

**TrackVisible**: when true, the trackbar is visible on the TPlannerItem
Unicode: when true, a Unicode caption and text is displayed for the TPlannerItem. The Unicode
caption and text is set with WideCaption and WideText properties. Only used in non-Unicode Delphi
versions!

**UniformBkg**: when true, CaptionBkg color has no effect

**URL**: string that can point to an URL. If URL is a non-empty string a link icon is displayed in the
TPlannerItem caption

**Visible**: sets the visibility state of the TPlannerItem

**WideCaption**: sets the caption as Unicode (widestring) text. Set Unicode = true in order to see the
Unicode text in the caption. Only used in non-Unicode Delphi versions!

**WideText**: sets the TPlannerItem text as Unicode. Only used in non-Unicode Delphi versions!

**WordWrap**: when true, TPlannerItem text is displayed with wordwrapping.

**link to manual** :
https://download.tmssoftware.com/Download/Manuals/TMS%20TPLANNER.pdf

Comment: thanks for instructions / corrections to  Blastfurnace, Mark Rotteveel, m4n0, CertainPerformance.         (I'm new to stackoverflow)